# call a function contain showModalDialog outside iframe show the wrong page

Tags: javascript, iframe

The site like this:

```
    `--main.html
    `--dialog.html
    `--folder
        `--iframe.html
```

and the code is here:
main.html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testframe() {
            var doc = document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow;
            doc.show();
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="folder/iframe.html" id="frame"></iframe>
        <br/>
        <button onclick="testframe()">test</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

dialog.html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    This is modal dialog!
    </body>
    </html>
```

iframe.html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show() {
            showModalDialog('../dialog.html');
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        this is ifram
        <br />
        <button onclick="show()">show dialog</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I click the show dialog button in the ifram,it show the modal dialog correctly.
When I click the test button outside the ifram ,it show the modal dialog incorrectly.

How can I fix this when I click the test button outside the ifram to show the correct page in the dilog?

Comment: What do you want to say when saying "incorrectly" ?

Comment: I wan to show the dilog.html in the modal dialog when I click the test button

Comment: yes, I've understand that, but why it does not run ? is there any javascript error in the firebug console ? Is the popup is showing badly (size, index...) ? Please, provide more information, this is hard to solve a problem without all keys...

Comment: the showModalDialog's uri argument is base on which page the function call,but not base on where the code wirte on.In the main.html calling the showModalDialog ,the uri is base on the main.html;in the iframe.html,it base on the iframt.html.but I don't know how to call the show() function in the mian.html to show the dialog.html

Answer (score 0):

```
iframeDomElement.contentWindow.setTimeout(function() {
   iframeDomElement.contentWindow.childFunc();
}, 0);
```

This hack will make the relative path relative to the child window. Works in firefox and chrome，but not in safari.